# android fragment using activity

Tags: android

I want to replace layout of activity with a fragment using onItemClickListener in a list

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(this, Answer.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Answer_0 answer_0=new Answer_0();
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_show,answer_0);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
```

When I click on item, then app shows ANR and shuts down.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What is the point of replacing fragment after startActivity?

Comment: I am using a listView in activity and using a onItemClickListener and wanted to change the layout of started activity with fragment layout

Comment: Put that fragment replace code on the activity you just started

Comment: I have multiple fragment that are to be replaced on item click  within a single activity

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your activity

```
public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

        }
```

and use like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            openFragment(new yourFragment1());
            break;

            case 1:
            openFragment(new yourFragment2());
            break;

            case 2:
            openFragment(new yourFragment3());
            break;
        }
```

and make sure you import `android.support.v4` instead of `android.app`

And do it after you open your activity

And if you want to load fragment when activity starts then put `openFragment(new yourFragment())` on `onCreate` method of that activity

Comment: I'm making an app that have fragments . 
The app have only two activities one is for questions arranged in listview with onItemClickListener and another is for answer. 
Every answer is arranged in corresponding fragment. 
When i click on an item of listview then answer activity started then I want to replace the layout of answer activity with the clicked item's corresponding fragment 
Project have files as follows..... 
QuestionActivity.java 
AnswerActivity.java 
questions_layout.xml 
answer_layout.xml 
and 40 fragments 
please help me

Comment: when you click on the item don't open the activity instead open an fragment with the help of code i provided you

Comment: Just make a blank framelayout where you want to load the fragment and replace that framelayout with your fragment

Comment: Did this answer helped you?

Comment: little bit i have used intent.putExtras() for sending the clicked list item on another activity and in that activity I used getIntent() method for recognizing clicked item of list and open appropriate fragment of that item